# how do I use a set method to add a string of colors to an array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a set method to apply 7 colors to an array in c++. I am not entirely sure how to use the setElement method in my main function to help me append colors to the indices in my array, as I cannot find any help online or in my book. So far, I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class randColor 
{
    private:

        string colors[7];

    public: 

    void setElement(index, "color")
    {
        colors[] = index; 
        index = "color";
    }

    void printColor()
    {
        int i = 0;

        for(i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            cout << colors[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    randColor RandomOne;

    RandomOne.setElement(index, {"red", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "green", "indigo", "violet"});
    RandomOne.printColor();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot "append" to a statically sized array. Those arrays have a fixed size that doesn't change at rntime

Comment: `for(i = 0; i <= 7; i++)` is an off by 1 error. With that said you should avoid magic number programming. Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)

Comment: `colors[] = index;` not sure what you were trying to do here but its not valid `c++`

Comment: `void setElement(index, "color")` You have to give your variables types. With that said the second parameter is a string literal and not even a variable name.

Comment: `index` seems to be some variable not defined in the code

Comment: Maybe you want to change `string colors[7];` to `std::vector<std::string> colors;` that would allow you to add colors 1 at a time to the vector and you could actually put more than 7 colors in your class.

Comment: You're trying (although incorrectly) to use a compound literal as the function argument. That's a C feature, but it doesn't exist in C++.

Comment: @UnholySheep sorry, I meant add lol

Answer (score 2):

`setElement()` is for setting just one element, you can't give it an array.

You need to declare the types of the function parameters, and they shouldn't be in quotes.

```
    void setElement(unsigned int index, std::string color)
    {
        colors[index] = color;
    }
```

If you want to set all the elements, you need to call it in a loop.

```
std::string rainbow[] = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "green", "indigo", "violet"};
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof rainbow/sizeof *rainbow; i++) {
    RandomOne.setElement(i, rainbow[i]);
}
```

Comment: FYI that you can replace `sizeof rainbow/sizeof *rainbow` with `std::size(rainbow)` in C++17 and later (Visual Studio also has [`_countof()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/countof-macro?view=vs-2019) available).  Or you can write your own `size()` function in earlier versions: `template<class T, size_t N> size_t size(const T (&)[N]) { return N; }`

Answer (score 2):

Your `setElement()` method is implemented all wrong.  It needs to look like this instead:

```cpp
void setElement(int index, const string &color)
{
    colors[index] = color;
}
```

Also, your `printColor()` method is going out of bounds of the array.  The loop needs to use `<` instead of `<=`:

```cpp
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++)
```

And then, your `main()` should look like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    randColor RandomOne;

    RandomOne.setElement(0, "red");
    RandomOne.setElement(1, "orange");
    RandomOne.setElement(2, "yellow");
    RandomOne.setElement(3, "blue");
    RandomOne.setElement(4, "green");
    RandomOne.setElement(5, "indigo");
    RandomOne.setElement(6, "violet");

    RandomOne.printColor();

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
int main()
{
    randColor RandomOne;

    const string colors[] = {"red", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "green", "indigo", "violet"};
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        RandomOne.setElement(i, colors[i]);
    }

    RandomOne.printColor();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to keep the `setElement()` function call in the `main()` function as is you could use an `std::initializer_list`, although I personally wouldn't recommend it in this case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>

using namespace std;

class randColor
{
private:

    string colors[7];

public:

    void setElement(int index, initializer_list<string> cols)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (auto it = cols.begin(); ++it; it != cols.end()) {
            if (i++ == index) {
                colors[i] = *it;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    void printColor()
    {
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < sizeof(colors) / sizeof(string); i++)
        {
            cout << colors[i] << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    randColor RandomOne;

    int index = 5;
    RandomOne.setElement(index, { "red", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "green", "indigo", "violet" });
    RandomOne.printColor();

    return 0;
}
```